# Redirect after login (Spring security on GAE)

Tags: java, spring-security

I am having some troubles making my login redirect to the same place always. I have done something like this

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="gaeEntryPoint" >
    <intercept-url pattern="/_ah/login" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="gaeFilter"/>
    <form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="authSuccessHandler"/>
</http>

<beans:bean id="authSuccessHandler"
            class="dk.lindhardt.arbejdsfordeling.server.security.AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl"/>
```

And

```
public class AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

   public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) 
   throws IOException, ServletException {
       if (authentication != null && authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
           response.sendRedirect(OrganizationListServlet.URL);
       }
   }

 }
```

It never gets into this method above. How do I make it do that?

Edit: I was following this guide http://blog.springsource.com/2010/08/02/spring-security-in-google-app-engine/

Comment: Can you share bean definition of your custom filter(gaeFilter)?

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't need to have that servlet there that then does the redirect.  You can have the redirect in the config itself.

```
<http auto-config="true">   
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/login" filters="none" />
    <form-login 
        login-page="/app/login" 
        login-processing-url="/app/dologin" 
        authentication-failure-url="/app/login?login_error=1" 
        default-target-url="/app/home"/>
</http>
```

Answer (score 7):

I think we can extend `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler` and call  `super.onAuthenticationSuccess()` method to use `DefaultRedirectStrategy`. The modified code will be:

```
public class AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
       @Override
   public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) 
   throws IOException, ServletException {
       if (authentication != null) {
       setDefaultTargetUrl(OrganizationListServlet.URL);
              super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
       }

   }

 }
```

Comment: SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler is a class and not an interface, so you need to extend it.

Answer (score 5):

You could do it without the Handler by adding the "always-use-default-target" to your form-login settings

```
<form-login default-target-url='/your/target/url.htm' always-use-default-target='true' />
```

See http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-form-and-basic under "Setting a Default Post-Login Destination"

Comment: I already tried this but it doesn't work. I am still redirected to the restricted page i tried to visit.

Comment: If it were me, my next test would be to try it without the custom entry point.  Simplify until it works, then re-introduce until you find what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not pretty but I solved it by positioning a custom filter at position LAST.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws
            IOException, ServletException {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

       if (authentication != null && authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
            User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
            if (user.isLoggingIn()) {
                if (authentication.getAuthorities().contains(AppRole.ROLE_NEW_USER)) {
                    ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect(RegistrationServlet.URL);
                } else {
                    ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect("/" + OrganizationListServlet.URL);
                }
                user.setLoggingIn(false);
            } else if (user.isLoggingOut()) {
                ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().invalidate();
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

I think the problem is that the gaeFilter bypasses the normal login procedure and therefore I can't use the authentication-success-handler.

Comment: 1. I think it is not the elegant solution. As shown in http://blog.springsource.com/2010/08/02/spring-security-in-google-app-engine/, there is no such thing as 'bypass normal logging procedure'. In that blog code, Luke Taylor has used failureHandler. Similarly the successHandler can be used.

Comment: Ok, can see that this is a better solution.

Comment: My down vote is locked. If you edit your answer, I will gladly remove it.

Comment: user.isLoggingIn() is not a method